# "OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space" error in my program

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Please have a look at the following code

```
public void createHash() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Hash Creation Started");

    StringBuffer hashIndex = new StringBuffer("");


    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
    Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
    s3.setRegion(usWest2);

    strBuffer = new StringBuffer("");


    try
    {
        //List all the Buckets
        List<Bucket>buckets = s3.listBuckets();

        for(int i=0;i<buckets.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println("- "+(buckets.get(i)).getName());
        }


        //Downloading the Object
        System.out.println("Downloading Object");
        S3Object s3Object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("JsonBucket", "Articles_4.json"));
        System.out.println("Content-Type: "  + s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());


        //Read the JSON File
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent()));
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) break;

           // System.out.println("    " + line);
            strBuffer.append(line);

        }

        JSONTokener jTokener = new JSONTokener(strBuffer.toString());
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(jTokener);

        System.out.println("Json array length: "+jsonArray.length());


        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //Add Title and Body Together to the list
            String titleAndBodyContainer = jsonObject1.getString("title")+" "+jsonObject1.getString("body");


            //Remove full stops and commas
            titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", " ");
            titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.replaceAll(",", " ");
            titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.toLowerCase();


            //Create a word list without duplicated words
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            for(String s : titleAndBodyContainer.split(" ")) {
                if (!set.contains(s)) {
                    result.append(s);
                    result.append(" ");
                    set.add(s);
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(result.toString());


            //Re-Arranging everything into Alphabetic Order
            String testString = "acarus acarpous accession absently missy duckweed settling";
            String testHash = "058 057 05@ 03o dwr 6ug i^&";
            String[]finalWordHolder = (result.toString()).split(" ");
            Arrays.sort(finalWordHolder);


            //Navigate through text and create the Hash
            for(int arrayCount=0;arrayCount<finalWordHolder.length;arrayCount++)
            {

                Iterator iter = completedWordMap.entrySet().iterator();

                while(iter.hasNext())
                {
                    Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
                    String key = (String)mEntry.getKey();
                    String value = (String)mEntry.getValue();

                    if(finalWordHolder[arrayCount].equals(value))
                    {
                        hashIndex.append(key); //Adding Hash Keys
                        //hashIndex.append(" ");
                    } 
                }

            }

            //System.out.println(hashIndex.toString().trim());

            jsonObject1.put("hash_index", hashIndex.toString().trim()); //Add the Hash to the JSON Object
            jsonObject1.put("primary_key", i); //Create the primary key
            jsonObjectHolder.add(jsonObject1); //Add the JSON Object to the JSON collection

            System.out.println("JSON Number: "+i);
        }

        System.out.println("Hash Creation Completed");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am not capable of running this code either in my local machine or in Amazon EC2, I get the following error

[image]

I am worried because this "test" is running on 6mb JSON file, while the original file will be terabytes. I am using  Linux instance in EC2, but I am not a Linux guy. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: All answers suggesting to increase the heap size should be deleted, IMO. Such advice is like instructing a victim with a severed limb where to get more blood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring hashIndex outside of the loop

```
StringBuffer hashIndex = new StringBuffer("");

...

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

    hashIndex.append(...);
```

This means that the StringBuffer keeps getting bigger and bigger as you iterate the buckets until it finally explodes!

I think you meant to declare `hashIndex` inside the loop.

Comment: The answers is a combination of you and @Andremoniy. I am glad if I can select both as the the selected answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a  very bad idea to construct `StringBuffer` object for passing it inside `JSONTokener`. This class has constructor directly from `Reader` or `InputStream`, so your code should be something like that:

`JSONTokener jTokener = new JSONTokener(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent())));`

Comment: Does that mean this will cause memory issue? Just curious to know?

Comment: The string buffer with all of the data loaded into it will certainly take up extra space.

Comment: The answers is a combination of you and @Lance Java. I am glad if I can select both as the the selected answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your java have run out of heap memory. You can increase your heap memory up to 4gb on a 32bit system. If you're on a 64 bit system you can go higher. If you ask for over 4gb on a 32 bit system you will get invalid value from java and it will exit.

Below is how you can set your memory heap up to 6gb on a 64bit system using cmd command:

```
java -Xmx6144M -d64
```

Comment: Increasing java heap space is by no means a fix, only a temporary stop-gap.

Comment: @hexafraction: I do not appreciate providing downvotes, but I agree with you. I am navigating through 60 billion records, so the Java heap size means "nothing".

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess I did not downvote this answer, although I would see reasoning behind that. +1 for technical correctness.